# more descriptive error message than "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, python-3.x

learning python, coming from a php background. 
Keeping it short. Is  there a way to get more descriptive error messages about the syntax error? like in php.
Example: print var should give something like "expecting ( " , instead of the standard "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Thanks

Comment: Note that this level of detail is not possible in general. Anything from a binary operator to a comma to a dot or assignment is syntactically valid there, and for all the parser knows the code in question may have redefined `print` for some of these to make sense. Still, a fair question.

Comment: Post the code that's giving you this error and perhaps we can be of more help

Comment: @inspector: He's not asking how to solve a specific error, he's asking if and how he can get more help from the parser to solve all such errors himself.

Comment: should probably be tagged [python-3.x] if you're going to complain about `print var` not having a ( :P

Comment: If I knew enough python to know where to 'properly' tag it, I wouldn't have needed to ask this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to use a solid IDE. I only tried a few before settling down for [Aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com/) which is free (as in freedom) and cross-platform, but I am sure that many other offer similar functionality.

IDE with syntax highlighting will try to parse your code even before runtime, and will signal you any mistake (sometimes they have "false positives" but this is the exception, they are normally very accurate).

Here's a screenshot that illustrate how it works.

This is the wrong code:

[image]

And this is the popup that shows when you hover over the red X mark.

[image]

As delnan correctly pointed out in the comments to your question, there are a lot of possible "right" things that can go after a `print`, hence the verbosity of the popup. Nevertheless I find this feature very useful, as it also shows you methods from unimported objects, variables referenced before assignment and so on and so forth.

HTH!

Comment: what the frak is wrong with the print statement (as it's not python3)??

Comment: @Franklin - I assume you think it's not python 3 because of the encoding declaration? However in any good IDE you can define your syntax rules, and my IDE is set on py3.0. The reason? Because I am running on Python 2.7 that accepts many syntax forms from python 3.x as for example `print('whatever')`, so I am making my life easier for the future by reminding myself already now to adopt the new syntax whenever is possible.

Comment: No *NIX system (that I know) has yet `env python` as `python3`... Also, you should do `from __future__ import print_function` instead of  using fake parentheses...

Comment: @Franklin - I think you misunderstood me. I am not trying to use python 3 interpreter nor to use any of the functionalities that Py3 offers over Py2. I am just checking my code (written for python 2.7) with the 3.0 syntax. That's all. :)

Comment: I fully understood that. But using `print_function` is much better than fake parentheses with old and deprecated `print statement` and you should use it instead.

Comment: @Franklin: Arch Linux has `/usr/bin/python` as python 3.

Comment: @mac: Consider `print('hi', 'there')`. You'll get very different behavior between 2 and 3.

Comment: @Daenyth - I appreciate your and Franklin's feedback, yet - beside being OT - I am not suggesting the OP to do the same (indeed I neither mentioned that in my answer). Checking py2.7 code with py3.0 syntax works for me. Here I am simply showcasing a feature of the IDE against the example the OP proposed (the `print` as a function, not as a statement)! But again: thanks for your feedback... **I am not rejecting it!** :)

Comment: ok I got an IDE pyscripter, which underlines in red if there is any syntax error! This is as good as anything I guess. Thanks

Comment: IDEs will make you highly dependent, incapable of coding even a few lines in a basic text editor in someone else's computer when you most needed.